# Moving files to folders based on creation date and foldername Python

Tags: python, file, file-handling, shutil

I'am quiet new to Python, but I have a very interesting case which might provide stuff to learn for us all. I want to do the following. I have created 3 folders on my desktop (Source, Destination and Archive). All the 3 folders contain the same 3 subfolders (A, B and C). Every now and then the 3 subfolders in Source are getting filled with files. Destination and Archive are empty (for now).

Now I want to make a file management-system which does the following every time I run the code:

1. Python checks for each subfolders (A,B,C) in Source, how much files are present. If there is at least  one file present in a subfolder (A,B,C) in Source then:

Only the last created files in the 3 subfolders (A,B,C) in Source will be moved to the 3 subfolders (A,B,C) in Destination. This means that every time I run the code the latest file from Subfolder A in Source will be moved to Subfolder A in Destination (etc. for B and C). However, the move will only take place if the file is at least 5 minutes old. So If a file has been created just 1 minute ago, it wont move.

If there are remaining files (which where not created last) then this will be moved to the subfolders (A,B,C) in Archive.

Please note that every time a files moves it has to be put in the subfolder with the same name as its previous location. So a file in Subfolder A can NEVER be moved to subfolder B.

This is the code I have right now, but I get Invalid Syntax. The code might not be complete.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import shutil, os

#Creating Source, Destination and Archive paths.
source = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\Source'
destination = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\Destination'
archive = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\Archive'

mod_time = timedelta(minutes=5)
now = datetime.now()
before = now - mod_time

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
   for file in dirs:
       if file > before:
           shutil.move(file, destination)
        else file:
            shutil.move(file, destination)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am just a beginner but here is my attempt to your question:

```
import shutil, os
import time
#Creating Source, Destination and Archive paths.
source = r'C:\python\here\source'
destination = r'C:\python\here\destination'
archive = r'C:\python\here\archive'

#Current time in seconds
current_time=time.time()

#First os.walk for the source folder itself
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for folder in dirs:
        subdir=root+'\\'+folder
        #second os.walk for each folder in the source folder (A, B, and C)
        for subroot, subdirs, subfiles in os.walk(subdir):
            for file in subfiles:
                filePath=subroot+'\\'+file
                #Gets the file descriptor and stores it in fileStat
                fileStat = os.stat(filePath)
                #st_ctime is the files creation time.
                #current time in seconds - file creation would be the difference 
                #between the current time and the file creation time.
                #Divide by 60 to convert that to minutes.
                ######################################
                ##If time passed greater than 5 minutes, send to a matching folder in destination
                if ((current_time-fileStat.st_ctime)/60) > 5: 
                    shutil.move(filePath,destination+'\\'+folder)
                else:
                    shutil.move(filePath,archive+'\\'+folder)
```

**Note:** in each folder source, destination, and archive I created subfolders A, B, and C.

Comment: Well I will try this one and and let you know how things worked out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried it out. It almost does what it needs to do. However, I did some tests and there are 2 problems. If I place 1 file in each subfolder  A, B and C and run the code then only the file from Source//A gets transferred to Destination//A. The files from Source//B and C get directly transferred to Archive//B and Archive//C. Besides that, If the files are NOT older then 5 minutes they need to stay in the Source folder.